# Angular factory works when page loads, not when called by a function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

The following code, specifically the planetFactory part works when the page is initially loaded. Meaning, a new Planet object is created with 7 default rings. However if a function is called to assign a new Planet object to `$scope.planet` nothing happens. In the sample code, if you add a name or diameter, and then click create new planet, there is no call to the planetFactory.

What am I missing about factories here?

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['appControllers', 'appServices']);

var appControllers = angular.module('appControllers', [])
  .controller('main', ['$scope', 'planetFactory', function($scope, planetFactory) {
    $scope.planet = planetFactory;
    $scope.newPlanet = function () {
      console.log('This part is actually executed but no factory call');
      $scope.planet = planetFactory;
    }
  }]);

var appServices = angular.module('appServices', [])
  .constant('defaultRings', 7)
  .factory('planetFactory', ['defaultRings', function (defaultRings) {
   console.log('Factory called, logging this message');
   function Planet (rings) {
    this.name;
    this.diameter;
    this.rings = rings;
   }
   return new Planet(defaultRings);
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<h3>Change the name or diameter so to confirm creating a new planet doesnt work</h3>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="main">
Name <input type="text" ng-model="planet.name"> <br/>
Diameter <input type="text" ng-model="planet.diameter"> <br/>
<hr/>
  Planet object: <br/>
  Name: {{ planet.name }} <br/>
  Diameter: {{ planet.diameter }} Km <br/>
  Rings: {{ planet.rings }}<br/>
  <input type="button" ng-click="newPlanet()" value="Create new planet">
  <br/><br/><br/>
</div>
```

Comment: Factory is function type, and it's normal if you get first console without any conditions, but all functions inside your factory still private until you call them from your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Found the correct way to use Factories for this particular purpose [in this excellent guide from Todd Motto](https://toddmotto.com/factory-versus-service):

The difference between what I was doing before and his method is that, the `new` keyword is not used inside the factory code, the factory returns the entire constructor, and then one calls the `new planetFactory` code from the actual controller.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['appControllers', 'appServices']);

var appControllers = angular.module('appControllers', [])
  .controller('main', ['$scope', 'planetFactory', function($scope, planetFactory) {
    $scope.planet = new planetFactory(8);
    $scope.newPlanet = function() {
      console.log('This part is actually executed but no factory call');
      $scope.planet = new planetFactory(3);
    }
  }]);

var appServices = angular.module('appServices', [])
  //.constant('defaultRings', 7) --> not needed
  .factory('planetFactory', ['defaultRings', function(defaultRings) {
    console.log('Factory called, logging this message');

    function Planet(rings) {
      this.name;
      this.diameter;
      this.rings = rings;
    }
    return Planet;
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<h3>Change the name or diameter so to confirm creating a new planet doesnt work</h3>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="main">
  Name <input type="text" ng-model="planet.name"> <br/> Diameter <input type="text" ng-model="planet.diameter"> <br/>
  <hr/> Planet object: <br/> Name: {{ planet.name }} <br/> Diameter: {{ planet.diameter }} Km <br/> Rings: {{ planet.rings }}<br/>
  <input type="button" ng-click="newPlanet()" value="Create new planet">
  <br/><br/><br/>
</div>
```